# Where can I download mono-4.6.1.5?

Tags: mono

For a particular script, I need to download the package mono-4.6.1.5 for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
However, I can not do it from the official mono web site.
Anyone knows where I could get the .tar.gz package since the one I have is corrupted?
Thank you in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: mono-4.6.1.5 / ef43c15 / Source tar and tar.gz @  https://github.com/mono/mono/releases/tag/mono-4.6.1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always recommended to run latest maintained and compatible version of packages complying with the operating system, excluding specific cases such as experimental purposes and etc.

But if you still need this specified version, you can find the "`tar.bz2`" format file on this [page](https://src.fedoraproject.org/lookaside/pkgs/mono/). There are certain ways to install a `tar.bz2` file on Ubuntu, but if you need the `tar.gz` file, you can convert it by a similar way explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/357978/how-do-i-convert-tar-bz2-to-tar-gz).

P.S: I'm aware that this package is from a Fedora repo, but I have successfully tried and installed Fedora packages on my Ubuntu 18.04 before. I assume this might also work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, your page with the .tar.bz2 is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Ho, btw, I found another link in my archives: [mono project](http://origin-download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/)